Power calculation of transformer
I have a 40 VA transformer.

Can I operate this transformer at any power?

Now, I want to obtain a power of 220V and 40W in the secondary winding of this transformer. Here's what I did:



In this case, would I obtain a power of 40W?
My last question is, I can't establish the relationship between 40W and 40VA. There is no reactive component here, so how should we interpret 40VA in this context?


You rounded the current I to two digits. Using the two digits to calculate the resistor only two digits of your result are valid and three digits are wrong. Using P = U * U / R you get 220 * 220 / 40 is 1.21 kOhm.

To state the obvious, you would not obtain a power of 40W; you would get 48.4W, which is 21% more than the rating of the transformer. Saying 1.2k is "about the same as" 1k is fine for, say, a pull-up resistor but not when it puts you over the power limit of a component.
Also, it's unwise to operate components at their maximum ratings, I would build in at least a 10% buffer and run the transformer at 36W or less, which would require a 1344 ohm resistor plus whatever the tolerance and tempco require on top of that, so closer to 1.5k. If you want to dissipate 40W in the load, then you should use at least a 50W transformer. You must also verify that the insulation on the secondary side of the transformer is rated for 220V.
In this context, real power is the same as apparent power, since you have a purely resistive load.
